# How to remove uninstalled apps from search results?

Tags: search

When using the Start Menu to search something that has been uninstalled, it still shows up there. It does nothing when pressed, and right-clicking doesn't work, even after reinstalling the app.

I tried searching for them in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs and %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs, but didn't find anything.

I tried rebooting several times but it didn't work. 
I even tried using CCleaner to clear registry but it didn't work either. Even rebooting several times didn't help.

Edit: I used [this](https://github.com/W4RH4WK/Debloat-Windows-10) Windows 10 debloater to remove those apps and they appear in the search bar

Comment: was it a system app? like Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Yes, one of them was Your Phone app

Comment: I think "Your Phone" isn't an app but a feature available in setting that allows you to link a phone and synchronize with PC.

Comment: No it is an application too, you can view photos, messages call logs from your device using that app